# Creating pandas DataFrame with nullable integer data type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, integer, missing-data

How can one create a pandas DataFrame with a nullable integer data type?

What is wrong with the example below?

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

# works
pd.DataFrame(index=list(range(2)), data={'x':np.uint8(1)})

# TypeError: data type not understood
# TypeError: values must be a 1D list-like
pd.DataFrame(index=list(range(2)), data={'x':np.uint8(1)}, dtype='UInt8')
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(index=list(range(2)), data={'x':np.uint8(1)},dtype=np.uint8)
` ?

Comment: ```pd.DataFrame(index=list(range(2)), data={'x':np.uint8(1)}, dtype=type('UInt8'))```?

Comment: Using 'Int64': `df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1, 2, np.nan]}, dtype='Int64')`

Comment: I did mean to use 'UInt8', not 'uint8'. [Recent pandas allows to have missing integer values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, one has to use the correct number of elements during the initialization if missing values are allowed:

```py
# works
pd.DataFrame(index=list(range(2)), data={'x':np.uint8(1)})

# does not work
pd.DataFrame(index=list(range(2)), data={'x':np.uint8(1)}, dtype='UInt8')

# works
pd.DataFrame(index=list(range(2)), data={'x':[np.uint8(1)]*2}, dtype='UInt8')
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame({'x':[1]}, dtype='UInt8')` works as is on pandas 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

All three works for me, you should have `'uint8'` and not `'UInt8'`.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> pd.DataFrame(index=list(range(2)), data={'x':np.uint8(1)})
   x
0  1
1  1
>>> pd.DataFrame(index=list(range(2)), data={'x':np.uint8(1)}, dtype='uint8')
   x
0  1
1  1
>>> pd.DataFrame(index=list(range(2)), data={'x':[np.uint8(1)]}, dtype='uint8')
   x
0  1
1  1
```